# How to find highest number in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I needed to make a leveling leaderboard command for my Discord bot which has all the levels stored, but every user counts as a different array heres an example of some levels that has been stored.

```
 "356260305371791360": { "xp": 11114, "level": 38 },
 "368009051021508618": { "xp": 6610, "level": 23 },
 "437022946783920148": { "xp": 8822, "level": 30 },
 "555153623143677975": { "xp": 9804, "level": 33 },
 "484534061650542602": { "xp": 1598, "level": 6 },
 "562255044590960650": { "xp": 280, "level": 1 },
 "547567997900947466": { "xp": 3100, "level": 11 }
```

I needed help to know how to go through each array and find the highest number (which is xp).

Comment: those are objects, not arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#sort` if you first get an array of keys or values from your score map. Below I get an array of keys and use it to sort, then take the top five results and display them. If you just want the very top result, get the first element instead of using `.slice(0,5)`.

```js
let userScores = {
  "356260305371791360": { "xp": 11114, "level": 38 },
  "368009051021508618": { "xp": 6610, "level": 23 },
  "437022946783920148": { "xp": 8822, "level": 30 },
  "555153623143677975": { "xp": 9804, "level": 33 },
  "484534061650542602": { "xp": 1598, "level": 6 },
  "562255044590960650": { "xp": 280, "level": 1 },
  "547567997900947466": { "xp": 3100, "level": 11 }
};

let topFive = Object.keys(userScores).sort((a,b) => userScores[b].xp - userScores[a].xp).slice(0,5);

console.log("Top five:\n" + topFive.map(id => `User ${id} with ${userScores[id].xp} xp`).join('\n'));
```